# Problema para cambiar la posicion de un item en un array con VUE

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de hacer un reordenamiento mediante un botón en VUE, pero no puedo plantear la lógica y no me funciona correctamente.
La idea es que apretando el botón en la columna reordenamiento, baje o suba la posición de dicha pregunta respectivamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero lo que hago es mando un post por axios para que me devuelva las preguntas pertenecientes a x elemento, y después atravez del response me devuelve la lista correctamente, sin más preambulos el codigo:
Como verán no puedo ni plantear la forma de hacerlo, tengo una idea más o menos. Podría pasarle el id por parametro al metodo de la propiedad computada, sumarle 1 a dicho ID si es la fecha para arriba, de ser la otra sería otro metodo y restarle 1 a dicho ID, pero no se como remplazar el valor del otro item que tendría el mismo valor de position.

HTML:

```
<tr v-for="item in datos.lists">
  <th scope="row">{{ item.position }}</th>
  <td>{{ item.rule }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.type }}</td>
  <td class="text-center"> <ion-icon @click="changePosition('datos.lists, item, item.position, moverArriba')" name="arrow-up"></ion-icon> <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon></td>

</tr>
```

JS:

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      datos:{
        estado: false,
        lists:[
            { rule:'' },
            { type:'' },
            { position:'' }
        ],
        examID: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      postPost() {
            var examenID = vue.datos;
            axios.post(`getPreguntas.php`, examenID).then(response => {
                    if (response.data.error) {
                        vue.noteMsg('danger', response.data.message)
                    } else {
                      vue.datos.lists = response.data.lista,
                      vue.datos.estado= true
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    vue.noteMsg('danger', error)
                });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        searchUser: function() {
            return this.lists.filter((item) => item.name.includes(this.name));
        },
        changePositionUp: function(id){
           this.lists.item.position = id + 1;
        }
    }
});
```

PD: Tengo claro que una vez cambiada la posición, haré otro axios post con un boton guardar, para que salve los datos nuevamente en la bdd.

## Intentos

```
changePosition(array, item, posicion, tipo) {
  if (tipo === 'moverArriba') {
    var posicionActual = array.item.posicion;
    for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
      if (array[i] === posicionActual) {
        var nuevaPosicion = array[i] + 1;
      }
      if (array[i] === nuevaPosicion) {
        var eldearriba = array[i] - 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(nuevaPosicion, eldearriba);
}
```

### segundo intento

```
 changePositionUP(array, item, posicion) {
  var posicionActual = array.item.posicion;
  for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
    if (array[i].posicion === posicionActual) {
      var nuevaPosicion = array[i].posicion + 1;
    }
    if (array[i].posicion === nuevaPosicion) {
      var eldearriba = array[i].posicion - 1;
    }
  }
  return console.log(nuevaPosicion, eldearriba);
}
```

Comment: El id no puede ser la columna por la que ordenes.. deberias tener una columna orden

Comment: usas algún índice al momento de pintar?

Comment: @gbianchi no uso el id la columna por la que ordeno, es una tabla position que la traigo por PHP, es lo mismo que orden digamos, en la funcion le paso el ID pero en realidad lo que hace referencia es a la posicion.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si, uso una tabla position y a la hora de hacer la query, hago  ORDER BY position .

Comment: Me refiero al front_end, normalmente se hace con `key="item.id"`

Comment: @RuslanLópez Ah, yo lo estoy utilizando de esta forma:  <tr v-for="item in datos.lists">
      <th scope="row">{{ item.position }}</th>

Comment: no tenes que cambiar el id.. la grilla no se dibuja por id, se dibuja por el orden de las filas en el objeto.. tenes que reconstruir el objeto con el orden que queres...

Comment: Vale @Jeritok agrégale una función a tu elemento como un onclick y debes de pasarle tu arreglo, item y tu item.position para que pueda modificarlo, en la función buscas el item y en base al nombre de la función moverArriba o moverAbajo haces la modificación de los valores en el arreglo.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Okey, entiendo lo que planteas. Pero, a que elemento le hago el onclick? Eso no entendí, porqué tecnicamente tendría que ser a las flechas de arriba y abajo, pero en ese caso no podría implementar la funcion que vos me planteas

Comment: @gbianchi Perdón si me especifique mal, la grilla no esta dibujada por ID, esta dibujada por una tabla posicion, que la traigo por PHP y le hago un ORDER BY posicion

Comment: y los botones como estan dibujados??? la pregunta es interesante, pero me paree que no tiene los datos que importan y si un monton que no importan.. puede ser?

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí edite el html como están dibujados los botones, tengo todos los datos que necesito digamos, el nombre, el tipo que son dos cosas externas a las modificaciones que hagamos, y la columna dibujada como ID, en realidad es POSICION, pero puse ID para evitar confusiónes con el cliente. Pero ya con la posición debería poder realizar el algoritmo, no se que datos decís que faltan, y cuales sobran. PD: El evento click en el botón de la flecha de arriba recién lo estoy armando en base al o que me dijo la otra persona.

Comment: @Jeritok un método para tu icono arrow-up y uno para tu arrow-down. Com modificar tu modelo debería de bastar. Por ello es que te sugiero pasarle todos los elementos necesarios, por ejemplo, puedes también pedirle un índice en el v-for, o incluso `v-for="(value, key, index) in object"` y pasar estas variables a tu función para facilitartela implementación.

Comment: @RuslanLópez no se, traté de hacerlo de esta forma una función unica y le pasaba como parámetro el tipo de acción que debería realizar.

Comment: La función quedo así:   changePosition(array, item, posicion, tipo){
      if(tipo === 'moverArriba'){
         var posicionActual = array.item.posicion;
         for(i=0 ; i<array ; i++){
           if(array[i]=== posicionActual){
              var nuevaPosicion = array[i] +1;
           }
           if(array[i] === nuevaPosicion){
              var eldearriba =  array[i] - 1 ;
           }
         }
     }
    console.log(nuevaPosicion, eldearriba);
} Pero igualmente no pude,y ya me queme demasiado.Voy a intentar a plantearlo de hacerlo en PHP, desde ya muchas gracias a ambos.

Comment: falla porque array[i] es de tipo item y no necesitas cambiarlos de posición en el arreglo, sino intercambiar los valores de su `array[i].posición`. Y para siplificar la lógica te sugerí dos métodos uno para mover hacia arriba y otro para mover hacia abajo.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Bueno no me voy a dar por vencido jaja, ya separe los métodos, es algo así lo que me planteas? changePositionUP(array, item, posicion){

         var posicionActual = array.item.posicion;
         for(i=0 ; i<array ; i++){
           if(array[i].posicion === posicionActual){
              var nuevaPosicion = array[i].posicion +1;
           }
           if(array[i].posicion === nuevaPosicion){
              var eldearriba =  array[i].posicion - 1 ;
           }
         }
     
        return console.log(nuevaPosicion, eldearriba);
      }

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si no , no estaría entendiendo como decís que intercambie los valores del array posición. Lo que hago es que cuando recorra la posición, y sea la misma que le paso por parametro, creo una nuevaPosicion que sería la que tiene posicionactual+1 digamos, y después hago otro if para que el item que tenga ese valor originalmente, le resto uno y lo guardo en otro valor

Comment: @Jeritok array.item te debe de marcar error, ya que los arreglos no tienen un elemento llamado item. El otro error que veo es que no estás realmente intercambiando posiciones, sino que simplemente las estás imprimiendo.

Comment: @RuslanLópez ya lo pude solucionar de otra forma, ahí dejo el código arriba como solución.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUCION FUNCIONAL que implemente por si alguno necesita:

HTML :

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <th scope="row"></th>
  <td>{{ item.rule }}</td>
  <td> {{ item.type }}</td>
  <td>         <ion-icon  @click="move(index,index-1)"
              :disabled="index==0" name="arrow-up">
  </ion-icon>            

              <ion-icon   @click="move(index,index+1)" 
              :disabled="index==(items.length-1)" name="arrow-down"></ion-icon></td>

</tr>
```

JS :

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return this;
};


var vue = new Vue({
    el: "#vue", 

    data: {
      datos:{
        examID: ''
      },
        estado: false,
        items: [
            { question_id :'' },
            { rule:'' },
            { type:'' }

        ]

    },
    methods: {
        postPost() {
            var examenID = vue.datos;
            axios.post(`getPreguntas.php`, examenID).then(response => {
                    if (response.data.error) {
                       alert('danger', response.data.message)
                    } else {
                      this.items = response.data.lista,
                      this.estado= true
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert('danger', error)
                });
        },
        move(from, to) {
            this.items.move(from, to);
        },

        guardarPosiciones(){
          var arrayNuevo = this.items;
          axios.post(`setPosiciones.php`, arrayNuevo).then(response => {
                    if (response.data.error) {
                       alert('danger', response.data.message)
                    } else {
                     alert('info',  response.data.message)
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    alert('danger', error)
                });
        }
    }

});
```